# Android phonegap input text not working position:fixed

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

Android phonegap input text not working position:fixed.

**Problem:**
In English language INPUT fills in other languages ​​do not.
But if you remove the position:fixed in css .top-navbar-panel input works.

**head:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

**css:**

```
.top-navbar-panel {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;

    background: #ff5050;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fa4444 0%, #fa4444 #ec1212 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fa4444 ), color-stop(100%,#ec1212));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fa4444  0%,#ec1212 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fa4444   0%, #ec1212 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fa4444  0%, #ec1212 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fa4444  0%, #ec1212 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=' #f81e1e ', endColorstr='#ec1212',GradientType=0 );

    padding: 0px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="top-navbar-panel">

        <ul>
            <li id="btn_all_discount" class="top-nav-active"> <img src="img/devices_logo_w.png" style="height: 50px;vertical-align: middle;margin-left: 9px;margin-top: -14px;margin-right: -18px;float: left;">  <span>All</span></li>
            <li id="btn_auth">Auth</li>
            <li id="btn_top_search" class="top-nav-search"><img src="img/ico_search.png" style="width: 100%; width: 65%;vertical-align: middle;"> </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="search_top_navbar_panel">
            <input  id="filter" name="search_top_navbar_panel" placeholder="Search..." type="search">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try adding `left:0` too

Comment: The input is not displayed to you because if you have given postion:fixed you have to align your tags with top,left CSS attribites .

Comment: does not work "try adding left:0"